# Read LTO memory chip with a drive older than the tape

Tags: memory, lto

That is the question. Can I read the data inside the memory chip of a lto7 tape using an lto6 drive?
I have only tried ITDT on windows but it rejects to do anything with the tape.
Just asking in case it would be posible, otherwise I would have to buy one of those usb readers that can be used with open source software to read the data, but would love to skip this method.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: AFAIK LTO devices have only backward compatibility (two levels) with tapes so you tape device can work with LTO6 tapes, can write to LTO5 and can read from LTO5 tapes. I do not remember to be mentioned something about next generation compatibility.

Comment: https://www.lto.org/lto-generation-compatibility/

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But I am not talking about the tape itself, but about its memory chip. The one that stores information about how many times a cartdrige was inserted, what amounts of data have been writen to it, etc.

Comment: Seems like this answer may answer your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/601158/101265

Comment: The document, mentioned in answer is http://publibfi.boulder.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/a3204509.pdf page 73

Comment: Thanks Romeo. I saw the thread you mention and read the document as well. Still I could not get clear about the question of an LTO 6 drive being able to read the radio frecuency memory chip in an LTO 7 cartdrige. I'm a film postproduction user, no programmer skills. If this is posible to do, could anybody point me in the right direction on how to? Thanks again!